# How to pickup file contents from HTML file input and hand off to API

Tags: python-asyncio, pyscript

I can successfully send image data to an API endpoint with pyscript (1).  I can also set up a form and pickup the binary data from a file.  I want to put these together so that I pick up the image data and send it to the API in one call.  They both use `asyncio.ensure_future` but I'm not sure how to combine these two processes (getting file data and posting file data to an API).  Is there a way to combine these two processes with a single call to `asyncio.ensure_future`?

(1) send image data to API endpoint

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1" />

    <title>GET, POST, PUT, DELETE example</title>

    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="favicon.png" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.css" />

    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/latest/pyscript.js"></script>
    <py-config>
      [[fetch]]
      files = ["/request.py"]
    </py-config>
  </head>

  <body><p>
    Hello world request example! <br>
    Here is the output of your request:
    </p>
    <py-script>
        import asyncio
        import json
        from request import request  # import our request function.

        async def main():
            baseurl = "https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com"

        
            # CLD
            file = "data:image/png;base64,iVBORw0KGgoAAAANSUhEUgAAAAEAAAABCAQAAAC1HAwCAAAAC0lEQVQYV2NgYAAAAAMAAWgmWQ0AAAAASUVORK5CYII="
            body = json.dumps({"upload_preset":"<preset>","file":file})
            cldheaders={"Content-type": "application/json"}
            cldurl = "https://api.cloudinary.com/v1_1/<cloudname>/upload"
            new_post = await request(cldurl, body=body, method="POST", headers=cldheaders)
            print(f"CLD request=> status:{new_post.status}, json:{await new_post.json()}")

        asyncio.ensure_future(main())
    </py-script>

    <div>
    <p>
        You can also use other methods. See fetch documentation: <br>
        https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/fetch#parameters
    </p>
    </div>
    <div>
        <p>
        See pyodide documentation for what to do with a FetchResponse object: <br>
        https://pyodide.org/en/stable/usage/api/python-api.html#pyodide.http.FetchResponse
        </p>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

(2) process file from a form file input

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.css" />
    <script defer src="https://pyscript.net/alpha/pyscript.js"></script>
    
    <title>File Example</title>
    <py-config>
      [[fetch]]
      files = ["/request.py"]
    </py-config>
</head>

<body>

    <p>This example shows how to read a file from the local file system and display its contents</p>
    <br />
    <p>Warning: Not every file type will display. PyScript removes content with tags such as XML, HTML, PHP, etc. Normal
        text files will work.</p>
    <br />
    <p>No content type checking is performed to detect images, executables, etc.</p>
    <br />
    <label for="myfile">Select a file:</label>
    <input type="file" id="myfile" name="myfile">
    <br />
    <br />
    <div id="print_output"></div>
    <br />
    <p>File Content:</p>
    <div style="border:2px inset #AAA;cursor:text;height:120px;overflow:auto;width:600px; resize:both">
        <div id="content">
        </div>
    </div>

    <py-script output="print_output">
        import asyncio
        from request import request  # import our request function.

        import json
        from js import document, FileReader, console
        from pyodide import create_proxy
        from pyodide.http import pyfetch, FetchResponse
        from typing import Optional, Any

        async def process_file(event):
            #print(event.target.files[0].name)
            fileList = event.target.files.to_py()

            for f in fileList:
                #console.log(json.dumps(json.loads(f),indent=2))
                #console.log(type(f))
                data = await f.text()
                console.log("name",f.name)
                document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = data

        async def main():
            # Create a Python proxy for the callback function
            # process_file() is your function to process events from FileReader
            file_event = create_proxy(process_file)

            # Set the listener to the callback
            e = document.getElementById("myfile")
            #console.log("value of e",e.name)
            e.addEventListener("change", file_event, False)

        asyncio.ensure_future(main())
    </py-script>

</body>
```

sharing two scripts that show what I've done